# Python saying file does not exist when importing but clearly does

Tags: python

I am writing a simple pygame name generator for a little project and am trying to import a function I made but it says it does not exist. You can see: [image: here] that my from and imports are correct. The script that runs is fantasy name generator yet this error (in the screenshot) is produced. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

My folder structure:

[image: This image is of my folder structure]

Comment: Is the directory containing the module on your Python path? Is the module intended to be part of a package, or is it top-level?

Comment: For the future, if you want to indicate a problem is solved, don't edit the question, just click the check mark next to the best answer that solved your problem to indicate it's the "accepted answer", which has the same effect and is more useful to people looking for unsolved questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generate_name.py` is in a deeply nested package alongside the other module. Python 3 uses absolute imports by default, relative imports must be performed explicitly.

The relative import you'd want here is (note leading `.` indicating a relative name):

```
from .prefix_code_gen import prefix_code_gen
```

The absolute import path would match the same one you used for `generate_name` if you wanted to use it:

```
from functional.generators.prefix_code_gen import prefix_code_gen
```

I'm inclined to favor the relative import, since it will continue to work even if a refactoring changes the absolute path, as long as the two modules are still installed under the same package directory.

Comment: this worked but gave a soft error: "Relative import outside of a package"
I changed it to:

from functionals.generator.prefix_code_gen import prefix_code_gen

Comment: @JonathonMeney: That's... interesting. The fact that `from functionals.generator.generate_name import *` works implies that it is in fact a package. Are you perhaps mucking about with `sys.path` and sometimes importing `generate_name` directly (because `functionals/generator` is also in your `sys.path`, not just the root dir containing `functionals`), and sometimes via a fully qualified name starting with `functionals`? As a rule, you should try to write a basic `setup.py` and actually make an installable distribution, rather than half-assing it with `PYTHONPATH`/`sys.path` shenanigans.

Comment: I am doing nothing with path at all, here is the git hub repo if you want to take a look https://github.com/OsmiumCoder/Capital-and-City-Name-Generator